# Proper use of the_content filtering

Tags: the-content, filters

This is a bit difficult without posting scads of code, but my question is: What are the benefits of filtering through `apply_filters('the_content', 'anything');`, and given my example loop, am I filtering `the_content` excessively or inefficiently, or is there a better way?

I ask because I just tried the Shareaholic plugin, which is supposed to detect the end of the post and insert social links. In my loop however, I find that it injects itself each time `apply_filters('the_content', 'anything');` is called, which in my case is quite a lot.

Because I'm new to WP and PHP, and Shareaholic is an established service,  I just assume these problems are due to ignorance on my part. Shareaholic has a shortcode that I can implement directly into the template, but I just want some general feedback / validation / criticism on my approach, and any ideas how to clean up or what may be causing the issue.

My loop looks something like this:

```
    <?php /* Start loop */ ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php function_for_post_banner() /* filters 'the_content' to add a post banner */ ?>

    <?php get_template_part('templates/loop', 'switch');
    /* Switch tests for post type and applies conditional markup, handels post type media and calls 'the_content' specific to each case. */ ?>

    <? fuction_attachements();
    /* do conditional formatting with post attachments ie images, media & docs all filtered through the_content  */ ?>
    <?php /* End Loop */ ?>
```

Any advice on this is much appreciated -- thanks.

Comment: Pippins explains the_content filter and working with it pretty well in his blog post http://pippinsplugins.com/playing-nice-with-the-content-filter/ Hopefully it provides some insight.

Answer (score 0):

You want to *add* a filter to the filter queue on `the_content`:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'anything');
```

*WordPress core* then calls `apply_filters` within `the_content` function to run all filters in the queue:

```
function the_content( $more_link_text = null, $strip_teaser = false) {
    $content = get_the_content( $more_link_text, $strip_teaser );
    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
    $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
    echo $content;
}
```